# TextInput : when maxLength is full automatically focus next field

Tags: react-native

I have an issue in my app with TextInput for a bank card numbers digit (error because user not type all number 16 digits).

So I would like to cut CB number on 4 TextInputs and focus automatically on next field after filled the 4 digits. (as already seen it in the web app)

But when I focused the next field, the current became empty, even if the state is correctly set.

Do you have an idea about how can I do that or is it impossible ?

ie. see the onChangeText on this example (exp date actually) :

```
<TextInput
    ref='card_exp_date_mm'
    style={[styles.inputTxt, {width: 30, flex: 0}]}
    value={this.state.cardExpDateMonth}
    keyboardType='numbers-and-punctuation'
    placeholder='MM'
    returnKeyType='next'
    clearTextOnFocus={false}
    autoCorrect={false}
    placeholderTextColor={Constants.placeholderTextColor}
    maxLength={2}
    enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    onChangeText={text => {
      this.setState({cardExpDateMonth: text})
      //console.log('onChangeText', this.refs.card_exp_date_mm)
      if(text && text.length == 2){
        this.refs.card_exp_date_aa.focus();
      }
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={()=>this.refs.card_exp_date_aa.focus()}/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like [in this example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/42cbc55f5f2c64fa2ed0cacaf3c8f8991fad6137/Examples/UIExplorer/TextInputExample.ios.js#L237):

```
this.refs[nextField].focus()
```

You should really check this example out, it covers what you are searching for.